# How to find old commits and comments in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

For code review we use comments on commits in Bitbucket, no pull requests. Pretty straightforward workflow: person A pushes to feature branch, person B reviews, person A adjusts code and force pushes in same branch, cyclic until satisfactory.

Bitbucket sends out notifications for comments on commits and these notifications contain a link to the commit/comment so it is easy to reach; these links and the content remain valid even after the branch gets updated with a forced push, or even deleted.

However if I person A does not keep the notifications around and hence does not have a direct link to a specific commit, and the commit isn't part of the 'regular' git tree anymore because person B rewrote history, it turns out pretty hard to find it. There doesn't seem to be anything in the Bitbucket UI which can do this. Sometimes person A is lucky and still has it in the browser history. Or can ask person B for links. Or manages to make Slack's search behave and find the noticifation. Etc.

Is there a way to find any commit/comment in Bitbucket? Even a text search would be nice. More ideal would be a list of all commits for a branch, something akin to `git reflog` or `git fsck`. To be clear: this is about commits which have been deleted and of which the SHA isn't known, nor an issue ID nor a Pull request ID. And those commits also don't show in the Bitbucket Commits list. They are still reachable via bitbucket.org//commits/ though but for that the sha needs to be known..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i view all comments posted by users in bitbucket repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649225/how-can-i-view-all-comments-posted-by-users-in-bitbucket-repository)

Comment: @Niki I don't think so, unless i'm mistaken the answer there requires you to know a commit hash, and that's exactly what I do not have here.

Comment: Ohh, so i think manually in each commit you have to check the way here state it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017710/7316675

Comment: @Niki I'm afraid that's the same problem: I don't know the commits, and they are not displayed in the Commits list in Bitbucket anymore because they're overwritten.

Comment: Umm here even pull request id is not known right. I'm sure you must have gone through this still sharing it with you - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-there-way-to-retrieve-all-comments-left-by-a-user/qaq-p/646818. Good luck with this

Answer (score 0):

> the commit isn't part of the 'regular' git tree anymore because person B rewrote history, it turns out pretty hard to find it

It's not all that difficult. [From an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57095939/1352761) about locating dropped stash commits; find the orphaned commit:

```
git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk
```

I don't think this can be done in bitbucket's UI, although my experience with bitbucket is somewhat limited.

Comment: The question really is about Bitbucket, not locally with fsck or reflog..

Comment: @stijn Which I acknowledge in the answer. Still, better to supply some way to get the information than to leave the question unanswered at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Old comments on a repository from bitbucket, you can check out the Activity Tab on the right hand side which will give you all the activity including comments that have happened on the PR/repo....

[image: bit-bucket Activity]